# Progressive (or iterative) Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I read the other day about a special type of callback that progresses with you as you call it repeatedly. As in it does A the first time it's called and returns, then it does B the next time it's called. Eventually it signals in some way that the final action has been taken.

I can't remember what it was called and I can't find it in my history so I don't know what to search. I need help.

Comment: You might be talking about es6 generators. Each time you call the yield instruction, the generator returns and "pauses", and is called again from the last yield the next time you call the function

Comment: Perfect! I wish you had posted an answer instead of a comment. Lol

Comment: Yeah its alright, i'm not a reputation grabber ;) glad you found what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is `generator functions`. It has been introduced by ES6.

> Calling a generator function does not execute its body immediately; an iterator object for the function is returned instead. When the iterator's next() method is called, the generator function's body is executed until the first yield expression, which specifies the value to be returned from the iterator

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Example:

```
function* idMaker() {
  var index = 0;
  while (index < 3)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // undefined
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I'll accept the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You may be talking about generators:

```
> function* x() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; return 4; }
undefined
> var g = x();
undefined
> g.next();
{ value: 1, done: false }
> g.next();
{ value: 2, done: false }
> g.next();
{ value: 3, done: false }
> g.next();
{ value: 4, done: true }
> g.next();
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Generators can be used for asynchronous operations when a generator yields promises instead of values that it wants to return that it itself expects to get injected as a resolved values of those promises in the return value of the `yield` statement by the wrapper like that from `co` or `Bluebird.coroutine` - see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/co
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

This was the basis of the new `async` and `await` keywords in newer versions of JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function